# SQL Server string with date in it. Don't understand behaviour of LIKE '%[0-9]%'

Tags: sql-server, regex

My goal is to get column names in a table that contain date. They look like 'SMTH_2000/01/01'.

If I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_[0-9]%'
```

Works OK, but returns also columns with numbers (obviously)

If I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_[0-9]/[0-9]%'
```

Works also OK. And I thought 'hmm, '_[0-9]/' is able to find strings with 4 numbers between '_' and '/'

Ans I tryed to execute this query (added one more slash to the end):

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_[0-9]/[0-9]/%'
```

And it didn't work.

Could someone explain why in one case it matches [0-9] with 4 numbers(not with one) but in the other case it doesn't? I tryed to 'google' the answer but didn't find something about this.

Comment: Can you tell what it's matching ?

Comment: If you google for `LIKE` you'll find several thousand answers. `LIKE` is a SQL keyword with a well defined behaviour. It's *not* a regular expression. It allows only simple wildcards, `%` instead of `*`, `_` instead of `.` and a character range for single matches. You can't capture a date with it, unless you specify patterns for all characters, eg `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`

Comment: Trying to work with text like this is a very bad idea. `LIKE` typically results in a full table scan to parse the entire table. You should extract the date to a separate date column when loading the data and query this instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually, you helped me! your comment is the answer for the question 'why'. why don't you write an answer instead of comment?

Answer (score 3):

Here is your pattern

```
SMTH_2000/01/01
```

A SQL Server `LIKE` pattern you would use to match this might be:

```
%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%
   ^^ 4 digit year     ^^ month   ^^ day
```

Try this full query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%'
```

As @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned, working with dates in this way may not be ideal from a performance point of view, as it would render all the power of SQL Server's date functions not usable.  You could extract the dates into a separate date column at some point if you plan on running this type of query often.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query which satisfies the your pattern

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' 
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/%'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' 
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/%'
```